# Downloading zip files from google drive using SDK for PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, google-drive-api, http-headers

I have uploaded my site backup to google drive using Drive SDK for PHP `"google/apiclient": "^2.0"` it is working perfect in terms of uploading now I am trying to download that backed up files from drive using the same SDK but the issue is, on some servers it works perfect and on other server's it gives me `Header already sent issue`. I am making this a plugin for WordPress and involving header for downloading those files is not a good idea I know that but what should be the alternate of it. The code through I am downloading those files is as follow.

```
$tempID = Helper::getBackupById($backupID);
    $AT = Helper::get_Settings('google_token');
    $refreshToken = Helper::get_Settings('google_refresh_token');

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('CLIENT ID');
    $client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

    $client->setAccessToken($AT);

    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $request = $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
        $newAT = $request['access_token'];
        $newRefreshToken = $request['refresh_token'];
        Helper::save_or_update_settings('google_token', $newAT);
        Helper::save_or_update_settings('google_refresh_token', $newRefreshToken);
        $client->setAccessToken($newAT);
    }

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    $google_keys = unserialize($tempID[0]->google_keys);
    $parentId = $google_keys['g_folder'];
    $lists = $service->files->listFiles(array('q' => "'$parentId' in parents"));

    foreach ($lists as $list) {
        if (!is_dir(wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/Restore')) {
            @mkdir(wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/Restore', 0777);
        }
        $storeIn = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/Restore/' . $list->name . '.zip';

        $content = $service->files->get($list->id, array('alt' => 'media'));

        $headers = $content->getHeaders();
        foreach ($headers as $name => $values) {
            header($name . ': ' . implode(', ', $values));
        }
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $tempID[0]->file . '"');
        $body = $content->getBody();

        while (!$body->eof()) {
            file_put_contents($storeIn, $body);
        }

        echo "Done.\n";
    }
```

Now, my question is that, Is there any other way of downloading those files without involving any header in it. If yes just the hint of it would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried something and it worked perfectly the header portion in this code was of no use I just removed that code and it worked fine just for some one if he needed it in future here is the updated code.

```
$tempID = Helper::getBackupById($backupID);
$AT = Helper::get_Settings('google_token');
$refreshToken = Helper::get_Settings('google_refresh_token');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('CLIENT ID');
$client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$client->setAccessToken($AT);

if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $request = $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
    $newAT = $request['access_token'];
    $newRefreshToken = $request['refresh_token'];
    Helper::save_or_update_settings('google_token', $newAT);
    Helper::save_or_update_settings('google_refresh_token', $newRefreshToken);
    $client->setAccessToken($newAT);
}

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$google_keys = unserialize($tempID[0]->google_keys);
$parentId = $google_keys['g_folder'];
$lists = $service->files->listFiles(array('q' => "'$parentId' in parents"));

foreach ($lists as $list) {
    if (!is_dir(wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/Restore')) {
        @mkdir(wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/Restore', 0777);
    }
    $storeIn = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/Restore/' . $list->name . '.zip';

    $content = $service->files->get($list->id, array('alt' => 'media'));

    $body = $content->getBody();

    while (!$body->eof()) {
        file_put_contents($storeIn, $body);
    }

    echo "Done.\n";
}
```